# Calling a function 1ms later everytime it's called?

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function in a `setTimeout` starting from 10 milliseconds to 11 milliseconds to 12 milliseconds and so on, using the variable in a `for` loop. It's supposed to create a thousand of the same element but with increasing time between each, but it creates them all at the same time. I put my code below.

```
for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    var timeDelay = i + 10;
    setTimeout(create, timeDelay);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about your code doesn't work? What is `create`?

Comment: Question's title !== code

Comment: if create takes more than a millisecond to run, then you wont get what you're after. Also, setTimeout's are hardly millisecond accurate at the best of times

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - how so?, create is "called" after 10,11,12,....1009 milliseconds, that's 1ms later every time

Comment: @PatrickEvans I edited it, sorry.

Comment: setTimeout() waits a duration of time then executes. setInterval() runs ever duration of time. Remove your for loop, wrap "create" in setInterval().

Comment: @JaromandaX what about _everytime it's called_?? The code isn't triggered by the function's call. Plus the title describes some form of debouncing as I understood.

Comment: I disagree, I think the code is attempting to do exactly what the title, and the body of the question is saying - what is unclear is "nothing works" ... that conveys no information at all

Comment: The edited question makes more sense ... I think the problem is not knowing how a browser works :p

Comment: @SynchroDynamic How can I increase the time delay using setInterval? Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: @JaromandaX Different continents, different POVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know what your mistake was, but the following code works:

```js
var timeDelay=10;
function create() {
  
  // do something e.g. change HTML
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=timeDelay;
  
  if (timeDelay<1000) {
    timeDelay++;
    setTimeout(create, timeDelay);
  }
}
create();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```